# young sound designer looking for feedback

Tags: sound-design, foley, video-games, gameaudio, voice-over

I'm a young sound designer from London.
I've been working for a while on a video game trailer and I would like to get some feedback from you guys about what things could I imrpove.

I did all the audio, music, voice recording and mixing.

Any feedback or comments will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you some feedback!
I like long and constructive feedback so I will give that to you.

One of the things I really liked was that bottle smash, really good job on that sound effect. I also like the underlying music tones at the beginning and the end of the trailer.

Things I didn't care for is how everything sounded very close and could easily tell that all of the sound was recorded in close proximity thus it didn't feel like it was in a space/environment. When the guy gets hit at the beginning I thought it was a punch then was confused of the blood. If it happens to be a punch... great, but if it was supposed to be a stab then we should her some gore of the blade entering the body. The blood effect seemed a little odd to be because it was at a high frequency. Personally, I like blood spurts, gore, etc to sound a little bit lower than water due to the physics that blood is thicker than water. The spray is a little short and could have been a little longer.

Nice helicopter sound, but it seemed to fade far to quickly into the next sequence. Needs a lot more cloth foley type movements, and more harsh wind tones. In real life, if you are directly underneath the skydiver it almost sounds like raging thunder and harsh tone wind.

Needs a lot more foley such as cloth movements and when they are shifting and fighting there way to the location. Good job on the foot steps, guns and the vehicle.

For the night scene... More ambience and foley. Maybe low pass filter on the rain when they are in the building, it seemed empty and quite than automate the change when they are back outside. 
The "Drone in position" sounds like it came from call of duty... lol

Basically for the rest, more foley and ambience again.

Make sure to record with a bit of distance, specially with foley.

Remember, reverb and low end are your friends. haha

Comment: Thank you very much Luke.
I really appreciate the time you took to reply.

Comment: Did you record the sounds?

Comment: I recorded most of the foley and sfx, obviously not the guns, explosions or vehicles..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Luke. I really appreciate the time you took to reply. I don't know about the original idea, but I assumed it was a punch, a very powerful one, hahah. I'll try to add more thickness to the blood sound, but it will be tricky to mix with the amb/music because of the mid low freq of them. I agree with you on the helicopter, I need to make the transition longer. I worked a lot on the foley (I'm not an expert recordist) but you may be right about I need more and more complex ambient sounds. Thanks again for the reply. It really helps to get an outside point of view. Sometimes it's difficult to judge your work after weeks of going over it.

Comment: No problem.

For the blood spray; try this... Duplicate 3 to 4 more layers of the same blood spray effect. Keep the first one original pitch then lower the duplicate -2 or -3 in pitch then keep doing that for each layer then mix it to your liking. For the sound that you have now, since it's high in frequency content. Try one original and 2 or maybe 3 other layers. (On separate tracks)

Comment: What you could do is start and end the helicopter later. Automate a high pass filter to carry to the next scene creating suspense and fade or 'morph' the helicopter sound into wind and the heavy cloth movements.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the blood spray, that really helped!

Comment: Yes, I made the helicopter longer, that really made a different on that transition.

Comment: I was experimenting 8 hours straight understanding how EQ works with proximity and how it proximity really effects sound. I came up with a very good trick to help you out. Set up your mic near your speaker about 1-2 feet away. Make sure there is not unwanted noise in your room. You are basically controlling the proximity of the sound now. You can choose the distance you want but I found that I didn't need to go much more than 2 feet away from my speaker. Record it and either use that file or blend it in with the "dry" sound effect. -Let me know if it works for you!